# Recursive looping error in Scala Intellij

Tags: scala

How to fix the error in screenshot?

Scala
IDE : Inellij

[image]

The Code in setting.config appear like

```
package config

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object settings {
  private val config=ConfigFactory.load()

  object WebLogGen {
    private val weblogGen = config.getConfig("clickstream")

    lazy val records = weblogGen.getInt("records")
    lazy val timeMultiplier = weblogGen.getInt("time_multiplier")
    lazy val pages = weblogGen.getInt("pages")
    lazy val visitors = weblogGen.getInt("visitors")
    lazy val filepath = weblogGen.getString("file_path")
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: All errors and code need to be posted here directly as text.

Comment: And `val pages = pages(...)` is defining pages in terms of itself. Do you have a function/list called `pages` somewhere else? Are you intending to redefine it here?

Comment: do you have any method name pages, products and visitors?

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Thanks for your suggestion. i have edited the question.

Comment: the code is different from what you have in the snapshot and what you have posted.

Comment: @RamanMishra: ya Raman the code which pasted is from setting.config, where i have defined

Comment: @Rohini As you are defining pages, visitors and products as the term of it self the compiler is assuming it as recursion. so can you please tell me do you have any methods with the same name? which you are calling? val pages = pages(...)

Comment: @RamanMishra: no i don't have any methods with the same name. can we discuss this in chat please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181437/discussion-between-rohini-mathur-and-raman-mishra).

Comment: As said already, please don't post code or errors as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are using the wrong Variable name while assigning the value for:

```
val visitors = visitors(rnd.nextInt(visitors.length - 1)) 
val pages = pages(rnd.nextInt(pages.length-1)) 
val products = products(rnd.nextInt(products.length - 1))
```

please use right variables:

```
val visitors = visitors(rnd.nextInt(Visitors.length - 1)) 
val pages = pages(rnd.nextInt(Pages.length-1)) 
val products = products(rnd.nextInt(Products.length - 1))
```